# MVC when i press on the delete view is not displaying the data of the Model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this code

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult DeleteKamion(int id)
        {
            using (TruckCompanyEntities1 databaseKamion2 = new TruckCompanyEntities1())
            {
                if (id == null)
                {
                    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                }

                Kamioni KamionDelete = databaseKamion2.Kamionis.Find(id);

                if (KamionDelete == null)
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }

                return View();
            }
        }

        [HttpPost, ActionName("DeleteKamion")]
        public ActionResult DeleteKamionConfirmed(int id)
        {
            using (TruckCompanyEntities1 databaseKamion10 = new TruckCompanyEntities1())
            {
                Kamioni SoferDeleteConfirmed = databaseKamion10.Kamionis.Find(id);
                databaseKamion10.Kamionis.Remove(SoferDeleteConfirmed);
                databaseKamion10.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("DisplayUserDetailsKamion");

            }


        }
```

and this HTML

```
@model DarkoPage3.Models.Kamioni

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "DeleteKamion";
    Layout = "/Views/TruckCompanyLayout.cshtml";
}

<div class="page-content-wrapper">
    <div class="page-content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="portlet-body form container" style="background-color:white;">
                    <h2>Избриши Камион</h2>
                    <div class="form-body ">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-9" style="color:black;">
                                Марка :
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MarkaID)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                Модел :
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Model)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                Година :
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Godina)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                Поминати КМ :
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PominatiKM)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                Шофер :
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SoferID)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                Дата : 
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Date)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @using (Html.BeginForm())
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                    <div class="form-actions no-color">
                        <input type="submit" value="Delete" onclick="DeleteConfirmed" class="btn btn-success" /> |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Назад", "DisplayUserDetailsKamion")
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when i press the DELETE  view is not displaying the values of the model but when i press the delete button is deleting, but i want to displaying the information as well, please help thanks.

Comment: You not returning the model to the view - `return View(KamionDelete );`

Comment: What `DisplayUserDetailsKamion` returns, can you add specific code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is becaues you are returning the view emtpy.. the view is expecting a model. The data is fetched but not returned.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DeleteKamion(int id)
{
    using (TruckCompanyEntities1 databaseKamion2 = new TruckCompanyEntities1())
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        Kamioni KamionDelete = databaseKamion2.Kamionis.Find(id);

        if (KamionDelete == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(KamionDelete);
    }
}
```